# docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Tags: docker

```
docker run -d \
  -p 8081:8081 \
  -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME-admin \
  -e ME_CONFIG_ MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password \
  --net mongo-network \
  --name mongo-express \
  -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODE_SERVER-mongodb \
  mongo-express
```

im facing

```
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
```

Please help as i double checked capitl letters.

i tried other stack flow answers but still facing this error.

Comment: There's an extra space in the second `-e` line, after `ME_CONFIG_`; is that your issue?  The other two `-e` lines have hyphens `-` rather than equal signs `=` between the name and value, which will not result in a syntax error, but the values you expect to be set won't be.

Comment: That is totally the issue, because that space is causing Docker to treat `MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password` as the image name, and everything after that as arguments to the image.